# What header controls "keep on server" feature while sending smtp message?

Tags: delphi, smtp

I'm using Synapse smtp library to send smtp message. But message are not keeps on server. E-mail clients has "keep message on server" option, but how to set it manually?

Comment: You don't. It's a user option (the user decides whether to keep on the server or not, not the server).

Answer (score 9):

That is a user-defined setting for POP3 clients.  When a POP3 client downloads a message, it decides whether or not to delete that message from the server after downloading it.  It is not a feature of SMTP at all.

Comment: also might be used in naive UI for IMAP4 :-)

Comment: IMAP clients do not usually download messages, they leave them on the server and manage them remotely.  IMAP clients might download messages to a local cache for faster access, though.

Comment: i said about naive implementation, when pop3 client hastily extended to support imap4 connection without redesigning internals